# Get the last Id from database to a string/Int variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have to get the biggest `id` to a string or an int variable.

That is how I'm doing it:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $list = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    $lst = mysql_fetch_array($list);
    $resId= $lst[0];
```

`ResId` is that variable.

Is this going to work?

Is there a better way to do it?

There is no `AUTO_INCREACMENT`!

Comment: `select max(id) as max_id from table`

Comment: Could you please show me how to do that? Can I just put it in the variable or does it return an array which contains the results? @u_mulder

Comment: also, there is no AUTO_INCREACMENT. will `max_id` work?

Comment: @NirPes there is no AUTO_INCREMENT but are you properly saving ids on a incremental way?

Comment: "Is this going to work?" --> Have you tried it already?

Comment: How's the upvote motivated?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't auto increment or in any other way organize your id:s, there is no way to know which was the last one. (Unless you get the last inserted id when you're doing an insert query.)

Your query returns the greatest id, but if you haven't structured your code/table so that the greatest id is the last - then it won't return the last id obviously (oh well, it could).

As for your question if it will work. Why don't you simply try it out? You're much more likely to learn from trying your self than asking people for answers all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If `last` id is the biggest id (as I see from your query), then you can also use:

```
$q = 'select max(id) as max_id from `b_iblock_element`';
$q_res = mysql_query($q);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q_res);
$max_id = intval($row['max_id']);
```

And don't forget that **mysql_*** functions are deprecated and will be removed soon.

Comment: Removed? why? @u_mulder